# 1980s YA Sci Fi book series about youth becoming immortal

Tags: story-identification, young-adult, space-exploration, immortality

In the early 80s I read two YA novels with the protagonist an adolescent who, along with all the other children on earth,  had been made immortal by a plague or experiement run amok.   Plot of the first one dealt a lot with society coming to terms with the situation, the second had the protagonist, as one of the oldest of the immortals, part of the government of earth.   Third book would have been the protagonist leading a deep space exploration mission.

I have no idea if the books are any good or not, but I liked the ideas in them.

Comment: Sounds like [The Days of Solomon Gursky](https://japeland.wordpress.com/2013/05/28/5050-short-story-3-the-days-of-solomon-gursky/)

Comment: @Valorum - That does not look like a YA novel, though.

Comment: @Adamant - No, it doesn't. Which is why I didn't post it as an answer.

Comment: So...eternal youths?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Immortal Children](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/123693/immortal-children)

Answer (score 3):

These books are the *[Earth Song](http://www.goodreads.com/series/59952-earth-song)* series by Sharon Webb - *Earth Child*, *Earth Song*, *Ram Song*. As I remember they were pretty good.

Summary of *Earth Child*:

> When all the people of Earth become immortal through the Mouat-Gari process, Kurt Kraus, minister of World Culture, realizes that all creativity has died, and he must find a way to restore it.